# For loop function for single line in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a txt file which contains some animal and fruit names. * contain fruits and # contain animal. Just like below:-

```
*   apple
#  cat
*   banana
#   dog
*   mango
#   lion
*   graps
```

I want to sort down list and write like a table which given below:-

```
*  apple                   #  cat
*  banana               #  dog
*  mango               #  lion
```

I'm using a `for` loop for this:

```
for /f "useback eol=* tokens=1-5 delims= " %%a in ("my text.txt") do (
for /f "useback eol=# tokens=1-5 delims= " %%c in ("my text.txt") do (
Echo %%a   %%b
))
```

But it echoes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `tokens` are parts of a single line. For the first line, Token1=`*`, token2=`apple`, token3 to 5 are not defined. Same for each other line. For your example, `tokeins=1,2` would be fine, but I decided to use `1,*` to take account of animals or fruits whose names are two (or more) words (like `dragon fly`)

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a in ("my text.txt") do (
  if "%%a" == "*" (
    <nul set /p "=%%a %%b     "
  ) else (
    echo %%a %%b
   )
 )
 echo\
```

This uses a special trick to write a string without a linefeed in case the line starts with `*`
(`<nul set /p "=string"`)

Of course, this depends on alternating `*` and `#` lines in the source textfile.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `cmd` or a `batch-file` using the following. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell is available.

This code get the entire file contents into memory, the splits it into an array on the `*` character. The first, empty, array element is skipped. Then, the `NewLine` between the `*` and `#` lines is replaced with a few SPACE characters.

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Content -Path '.\fruit-animal.txt' -Raw) -split '\*' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | %{ '*   ' + $_ -replace [Environment]::NewLine, '    '}"
```

Here is the data file and example execution.

```
C:>TYPE .\fruit-animal.txt
*   apple
#  cat
*   banana
#   dog
*   mango
#   lion
*   graps

C:>powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
More?     "(Get-Content -Path '.\fruit-animal.txt' -Raw) -split '\*' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | %{ $_ -replace [Environment]::NewLine, '    '}"
   apple    #  cat
   banana    #   dog
   mango    #   lion
   graps
```

This will likely work well for you unless you have a -large- file.

If PowerShell Core http://github.com/PowerShell/Powershell is used (recommended), change it to:

```
pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-Content -Path '.\fruit-animal.txt' -Raw) -split '\*' | Select-Object -Skip 1 | %{ '*   ' + $_ -replace [Environment]::NewLine, '    '}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The task description, the example input and output data and the posted code do not match at all. So it is really difficult to understand what the task really is.

The first batch file code below is for reading all non-empty lines from a data file and merge each non-empty odd line with each non-empty even line together and finally replace the source data file with the temporary file containing the merged lines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "DataFile=Data.txt"
if not exist "%DataFile%" goto MissingFile
set "TempFile=%DataFile%.tmp"
set "LineOdd="
set "LineEven="

(
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%DataFile%") do (
    if defined LineOdd (
        set "LineEven=%%I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LineOdd!    !LineEven!
        endlocal
        set "LineOdd="
        set "LineEven="
    ) else set "LineOdd=%%I"
)
if defined LineOdd (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LineOdd!
    endlocal
    set "LineOdd="
)
)>"%TempFile%"

if /I not "%~1" == "test" (move /Y "%TempFile%" "%DataFile%") else type %TempFile%"
del "%TempFile%"
exit /B

:MissingFile
echo ERROR: There is no file "%DataFile%" in "%CD%".
echo(
pause
endlocal
```

It is possible to run this batch file with the string `test` as parameter to just output the final result instead of overwriting the source data file.

The file `Data.txt` contains perhaps the following lines:

```
*  apple
#  cat
#  dog
*  banana
*  mango
#  lion
*  grapes
*  pear
*  plum
#  mouse
#  canary
# hamster
* cherry
```

The result of the batch file above is:

```
*  apple    #  cat
#  dog    *  banana
*  mango    #  lion
*  grapes   *  pear
*  plum    #  mouse
#  canary    # hamster
* cherry
```

The second batch file code below really looks on the identifiers `*` and `#` at beginning of the lines to determine if the rest of the line should be on left or on right side in the output file. All lines not starting with `*` and `#` are ignored by this code.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "DataFile=Data.txt"
if not exist "%DataFile%" goto MissingFile
set "TempFile=%DataFile%.tmp"
set "DataLeft="
set "DataRight="

(
for /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%I in ("%DataFile%") do (
    if "%%I" == "*" (
        if not defined DataLeft (
            set "DataLeft=%%J"
        ) else if defined DataRight (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!DataLeft!    !DataRight!
            endlocal
            set "DataLeft=%%J"
            set "DataRight="
        ) else (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!DataLeft!
            endlocal
            set "DataLeft=%%J"
        )
    ) else if "%%I" == "#" (
        if not defined DataRight (
            set "DataRight=%%J"
        ) else if defined DataLeft (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(!DataLeft!    !DataRight!
            endlocal
            set "DataRight=%%J"
            set "DataLeft="
        ) else (
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo(    !DataRight!
            endlocal
            set "DataRIGHT=%%J"
        )
    )
)
if defined DataLeft (
    if defined DataRight (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!DataLeft!    !DataRight!
        endlocal
        set "DataLeft="
        set "DataRight="
    ) else (
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!DataLeft!
        endlocal
        set "DataLeft=%%J"
    )
)
if defined DataRight (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(    !DataRight!
    endlocal
    set "DataRight="
)
)>"%TempFile%"

if /I not "%~1" == "test" (move /Y "%TempFile%" "%DataFile%") else type "%TempFile%"
del "%TempFile%"
exit /B

:MissingFile
echo ERROR: There is no file "%DataFile%" in "%CD%".
echo(
pause
endlocal
```

This batch file can be also executed with argument `test` to just output the final result instead of overwriting the source data file.

The output for the same data file example above is:

```
apple    cat
banana    dog
mango    lion
grapes
pear
plum    mouse
    canary
cherry    hamster
```

It can be seen that on left side are the fruits marked with `*` and on right side the animals marked with `#` in the data file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~1`
- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `type /?`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from your specifics what exactly may be the content and layout of your text file, or regarding the output, what exactly you mean by table, and whether empty cells in those tables would be acceptable.

Whilst trying to keep the idea you were using, as much as possible, and based upon the example text file you've submitted, assuming that there will not be two consecutive lines beginning with `*`, and using a horzontal tab, as a cell separator, *line 3 `Echo([TAB]%%G`*, here's a quick example of something which may suit your purposes:

```sh
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /BIL "* #"
 "S:\ome\Directory\my text.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @(
    For /F "EOL=* Delims=" %%H In ("%%G") Do @Echo( %%G
    For /F "EOL=# Delims=" %%I In ("%%G") Do @Set /P "=%%G" 0<NUL)
@Echo(& Pause
```

Example output *(with the mis-spelling `graps` corrected)*:

```
*   apple       #  cat
*   banana      #   dog
*   mango       #   lion
*   grape
```

If you didn't want the `*` and `#` characters in your resulting output file, i.e.

```
apple   cat
banana  dog
mango   lion
grape
```

Then the code would be modified slightly, where line 3 would have `Echo([TAB]%%I`:

```sh
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /BIL "* #"
 "S:\ome\Directory\my text.txt" 2^>NUL') Do @(
    For /F "EOL=* Tokens=1,*" %%H In ("%%G") Do @Echo(  %%I
    For /F "EOL=# Tokens=1,*" %%J In ("%%G") Do @Set /P "=%%K" 0<NUL)
@Echo(& Pause
```